# Unable to run Cypress open command in Next.js project with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, next.js, cypress

I'm unable to run `cypress open` in my Next.js project with Typescript. Here's what I get after running the command.

```
% npm run cypress:open         

> todo-app@0.1.0 cypress:open
> cypress open


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50474/devtools/browser/067ddcd9-221c-4042-8544-08d3598b88d7
Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions. tsconfig-paths will be skipped
/Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:311
        return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
               ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS5095: Option 'bundler' can only be used when 'module' is set to 'es2015' or later.

    at createTSError (/Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:311:16)
    at reportTSError (/Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:314:23)
    at /Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:686:17
    at Object.compile (/Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:743:35)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:856:36)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/mohitnayak/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.3/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:859:16)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 5095 ]
}
```

It's basic todo app. Here's the link to the open [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mohit-nayak/todo-app-with-cypress.git). Please help me running Cypress for the project.

Answer (score 16):

Go to your tsconfig.json file and update the value of moduleResolution in this file.
i.e.

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

Here you need to replace the value "bundler" with "node".

I've tested and it works fine with this change.

Result after updating:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! One more things is, it opens the Cypress window but why is it showing "Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions. tsconfig-paths will be skipped" in the terminal? Just wanted to know more about it. Appreciate your help!

Comment: This is because, in the cypress, you have not set up the cypress.config yet. You need to set up this file. for detailed information please visit 
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration 
here you will find all relevant information.

Comment: @MohitNayak Can you please mark this post as answered if this solved your problem?

Comment: Wouldn't this affect your Next.js code? I think applying "moduleResolution": "node" to all your ts_node configs is dangerous.

Comment: We can make it separate if required. I didn't face any issues so far with this.